# Ratchet Websocket server stop responding after some hour

Tags: php, linux, websocket, ratchet

I am using ratchet for my websocket application.Below is my server code.

### chat-server.php

```
error_reporting(0);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$docRoot = "http://myshowcam.com/NewSite";
if (!isset($conn)) {
    $host = "127.0.0.1"; // Hostname    
    $user = "root"; // Username Here
    $pass = "xxxxx"; //Password Here
    $db = "myshowcam"; // Database Name
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $db . ';host=' . $host, $user, $pass);    
}
$server=IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())), 9000, "myshowcam.com");
$server->run();
```

To run the server i have used the nohup command as beolow

```
nohup php -q ratchet/bin/chat-server.php > ratchet_ws.log &
```

As the process stop working after few hour i have use a shell process to check if this server is running or not and if its not running will start the server again.

### check_process.sh

```
while true
do
if pgrep php > /dev/null
then
    echo Running
else
cd /mypath/project foldername/
nohup php -q ratchet/bin/chat-server.php > ratchet_ws.log &
fi
sleep 1;
done
```

Now instead of running the chat-server.php i am running this procss as below.

```
nohup sh chk_process.sh > check_process.log &
```

Now  my  chat-server.php running fine but its not responding after some hour.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`nohup sh` is not the best way to persist a WebSocket PHP script.  You can actually run the PHP script as a system service and control it with `service socket start` and `service socket stop`.

You do this by making a file `/etc/init/socket.conf` with the following contents

```
# Info
description "Runs the Chat Web Socket"  
author      "Your Name Here"

# Events
start on startup  
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn  
respawn limit 20 5

# Run the script!
# Note, in this example, if your PHP script (the socket) returns
# the string "ERROR", the daemon will stop itself.
script  
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/socket.php) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

Tutorial Reference: http://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/